# RegEx for company name variations

Tags: regex

I have a requirement to accept string values ONLY where they meet the following criteria :

1) Can start with special character if required
2) Must start with capital letter ( Even if the first character is a special character )
3) The string value must not have 2 special characters in a row ( consecutive )
4) The string value must not have 2 spaces in a row ( consecutive )
5) Accented characters are allowed ( eg: Faddas )
6) Enclosed values at the start of the string or at the end are valid but must be inside parenthesis ( ie: (Ltd) )
7) Numerics are allowed anywhere in the string value

I have the following regex value : `^(\(([^)]+)\))?[\@\#\$\%\&\*\(\)\-\_\+\]\[\'\;\:\?\.\,\!]?\p{Lu}+[\s'-]?\p{L}+(?:[\s'-]\p{L}+)+(\(([^)]+)\))*$`

**This works ok for the following tested values :**
Éast-Shipping-ltd
Éast-Shipping(LTD)

**But fails the next example :**
Éast-123Shipping(LTD)

Is there any way to allow for numerics mid string ?
I have tried [0-9] variations, [A-Za-z09] variations and p{N} variations but to no avail.

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a *REALLY* nasty pattern, but I was able to simplify it a bit and do what you wanted:

```
^(\(([^)]+)\))?[[:punct:]]?\p{Lu}+(?:[\s'-]?[\p{L}\d]+)+(\(([^)]+)\))*$
```

There are lots of useful shorthand character classes, including `[[:punct:]]`, which I used to replace your massive punctuation character class. To add the ability to include numbers, I put the `\p{L}` in a character class with the `\d` token, which will match any number (in any language, with the Unicode flag).

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YtySX0/2)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://quickbooks.intuit.com/learn-support/en-us/manage-intuit-account/acceptable-characters-in-quickbooks-online/00/186243#) we have some characters acceptable for company names

```
^[0-9A-Za-zÀ-ÿ\s,._+;()*~'#@!?&-]+$
```